# Powershell : import-csv with if condition

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I have a csv as below :

- Server    OS      HotFixID
- Comp1    Win12   KB452
- Comp1    Win12   KB453
- svrname3 Win8    KB134

I have written below script for checking OS and if its matched then it should check if the server is having the same HotfixID or not.

```
$file = Import-Csv .\Desktop\hotfix.csv
if($Win12 = $file | where {$_.os -eq "Win12"} | select Source, HotFixID)
{
Get-HotFix -ComputerName ($Win12.Source) -Id ($Win12.HotFixID)
}
else
{
$Win8 = $file | where {$_.os -eq "Win8"} | select Source, HotFixID
Get-HotFix -ComputerName ($Win8.Source) -Id ($Win8.HotFixID)
}
```

> problem is with output.. I have 2 Win12 server in csv, but I am getting 4 output 2 as duplicate.. I am able to understand that here one nested loop is running but unable to rectify it. Please!! let me know how can we fix this issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your example data seem to reference only 1 Win12 server - "Comp1". Do you want to check only 1 specific HotfixID per remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

Assumed I understood your task correct you should iterate over all elements in your CSV file and check each item indivually.

```
$CSVList = Import-Csv .\Desktop\hotfix.csv
foreach ($CSVItem in $CSVList) {
    if ($CSVItem.os -eq 'Win12' -or $CSVItem.os -eq 'Win8') {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $CSVItem.Source) {
            Get-HotFix -ComputerName $CSVItem.Source -Id $CSVItem.HotFixID
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple entries with `Win12` so `$Win12` is an array of `PSCustomObject`. When you use `($Win12.Source)` it will output an array of all sources. (`Comp1,Comp1`). `Get-Hotfix`  accepts this array and tests `$Win12.HotFixID` (which is an array, too) with each of the sources.  Thats the reason you get each Item the Number of times they apear in the CSV. To avoid this, process each line in the CSV on their own. If you want to keep your structure, your code would look like this:

```
if($Win12 = $file | where {$_.os -eq "Win12"} | select Source, HotFixID)
{
    $Win12 | foreach {
        Get-HotFix -ComputerName ($_.Source) -Id ($_.HotFixID)
    }
}
else
{
    $Win8 = $file | where {$_.os -eq "Win8"} | select Source, HotFixID
    $Win8 | foreach {
        Get-HotFix -ComputerName ($_.Source) -Id ($_.HotFixID)
    }

}
```

However the Code of [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) is cleaner and does the same.

Comment: I couldn't have explained it better myself. Thank you very much.